# Quay API to get the tag using filter_tag_name

Tags: curl, quay.io

In my scripts I'm trying to get the tag of an image from Quay using API. As per the [Quay documentation v1](https://docs.quay.io/api/swagger/#!/tag/listRepoTags), I'm passing query `filter_tag_name=like:<my-tag>`, this is returning all the tags instead of the tags that contain `my-tag`.

`curl -k -XGET -H 'Authorization: Bearer XXXXXX' 'https://myquay/api/v1/repository/mynamespace/myimage/tag?filter_tag_name=like%3Atag-29112023084058465' -Ls | jq`.

I tried read all the available documents from Quay but cannot find any document or examples especially related to tag filter